# Not able to import client certificate in Swift XMPP client

Tags: xmpp

I tried to use client certificate for authentication using [swift XMPP client](https://swift.im/swift.html) but not able to select certificate, although I already import certificate in Window client certificate.

Got below message from the client, click `ok` to continue exit the window certificate dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install certificate first in the OS then the list will show installed certificate in the system.

To install certificate create [**pfx**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-ssl-certificate-pfx-file-on-windows-server-machine/) certificate formate and double click to install the certificate.

To create PFX

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out my_certs.pfx -inkey example.com.key -in example.bundle.pem -certfile ca.pem
```

[image]